# Como agregar un método a una función?

Tags: javascript

En las promesas, por ejemplo haces esto:

```
New promise(function(done){
done();
})
.then(function(){doSomething()})
```

, Entonces mi pregunta es relacionada con la sintaxis de `then`, esta se aplica a la promesa anteponiendole un `.` , ¿ **Cómo podría yo hacer eso con una función mía?** , osea por ejemplo(En pseudocódigo):

```
function cualquieraCosa(b){
return !b;
}.revisar(function(){return true;});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te explicó @Sr1871, tienes que regresar un objeto del mismo tipo, te dejo un ejemplo que quizás te sirva:

```
//Esta será la función que nos servirá de constructor
function TuObjeto(){
    //Aquí le podremos agregar métodos usando this
    this.metodo = function (){
        //Retornamos this para permitir el encadenamiento
        return this;
    }
}

//También podrías añadir más métodos de esta manera
TuObjeto.prototype.metodo2 = function (){
    //También retornamos this
    return this;
}

//Y podrías usar tu objeto y sus métodos de la siguiente manera
var mi_objeto = new TuObjeto();

//Y llamar a sus métodos
mi_objeto.metodo();
mi_objeto.metodo2();
```

Y como ambos métodos retornan `this`, es posible encadenar los métodos de esta manera:

```
mi_objeto.metodo().metodo2();
```

Si no retornas `this` no podrás encadenar más métodos que pertenezcan al tipo de objeto que creaste.

Espero y te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que regresar Un objeto del mismo tipo, es decir

`CualquierCosa()` es un método de un objeto de la clase o el prototipo `Foo`, por lo que para que puedas usar revisar debes devolver un objeto `Foo`.

Por ejemplo:

```
function CulaquierCosa() {
 console.log('primera cosa');
 return this;
}

function verificar() {
  console.log('segunda cosa');
}
```

Al estar devolviendo el objeto puedes usar cualquier otro método o inclusive el mismo.

Es importante aclarar que estos método deben pertenecer a un prototype o a una clase, si quieres concatenar las funciones debes devolver un objeto de la misma clase y de esa forma puedes concatenar n funciones, tener cuidado ya que en js algunos métodos como por ejemplo si usarás dentro de tu función `setInterval` el `this` puede no estar haciendo referencia a la clase o prototype.